# QGIS: CC-BY-SA licence label appears multiple times

Tags: qgis

I'm working on QGIS and even with a new blank project I see 8 times the label "CC-BY-SA" in the bottom right corner (see image). Why is that? What can I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the place to ask this. This isn't related to programming. Try in QGIS forums, but that shouldn't be a problem, since it's only a label for CC license

Comment: are you sure your project is empty? what plugins do you have active